# Rails how to remove UTC offset text ('UTC') from a dateTime leaving only the DateTime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a tool set to store everything in the db as UTC.    On a form I have a text field with an attached jQuery Date + Time picker.

In that textfield the dateTime stamp (w/ UTC offset) will just appear like:

```
<%= f.text_field :report_time, :size => 22  %>
    2012-06-05 15:55:50
```

However I need this form choice to be in EST.  So I need to convert it going to the form and then when the form is submitted.   This problem is specific only to when an 'EDIT' action is taken (time already exists in field).  If I do any addition or subtraction "UTC" gets stuck on the end in the form text field:

```
@report.report_time = @report.report_time - 5.hours
=>2012-06-05 10:55:50 UTC
```

At this point a jQuery DateJS dateparse function I'm using will stop working because it doesn't understand the "UTC" text in the text field holding the dateTime.

How can I take a db UTC time and add/subtract hours without "UTC" getting dropped in the form, or how can you remove the UTC offest information leaving only the raw dateTime information?

How do I:

```
@report.report_time = @report.created_at - 5.hours
=>2012-06-05 10:55:50 UTC
#  do something here to strip " UTC" off the dateTime   ??
=>2012-06-05 10:55:50
```

Thank You!
Rails 2.3.5 / Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Maybe just let it go and use a JS function on Document ready to convert the text (like strip the last 4 characters off the time in the text field) - or maybe using a text_field tag and specifying the value of the field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the strftime function to set the value of the field directly, if you don't want the default representation.

```
<%= f.text_field :report_time, :size => 22, :value =>"...." %>
```

http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-strftime

You may probably want to check out this link for information on how to use the date/time more naturally with the form builder.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#using-date-and-time-form-helpers